# Status bar app does not show file picker correctly

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I'm working on status bar app.

[image]

I want to show file picker to select my image.
Here is my code:

```
Button("Select image") {
            let openPanel = NSOpenPanel()
            openPanel.prompt = "Select File"
            openPanel.allowsMultipleSelection = false
            openPanel.canChooseDirectories = false
            openPanel.canCreateDirectories = false
            openPanel.canChooseFiles = true
            openPanel.allowedFileTypes = ["png","jpg","jpeg"]
            openPanel.begin { (result) -> Void in
              if result.rawValue == NSApplication.ModalResponse.OK.rawValue {
                let selectedPath = openPanel.url!.path
                if let nsData = NSData(contentsOfFile: selectedPath) {
                  imageData = Data(referencing: nsData)
                }
              }
            }
          }
```

It's shown, but behind my app (which is not on status bar)

So how to just show file picker and hide that weird view.

[image]